# 2d array squares initialization and selection

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, javafx, 2d

For code optimization purposes, I want to create a 2d array that contains 40 equal squares (10x10px). Each square represents 1\40 of the displayed window (400x400px).

I populate the 2d array with the standard double for-loop methodology.

```
    int col = 40;
    int row = 40;
    int boxPosition = 0; //Position of the box (coordinates)
    Integer[][] boxes = new Integer[40][40];

    for (int i = 0; i < col; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {
            boxes[i][j] = boxPosition;
            boxPosition += 10; //Creates a 10px box.
        }
        boxPosition = 0; //Resets box size for next column
    }
```

**There are several circles** in this program. We have a ship(circle) that fires missiles(circles) toward enemies(circles).

I want to run collision detection ONLY when there is a bullet + an enemy in one of the squares. This will greatly optimize the code.

The question is... how do I create these squares off of a 2d array? How do I select each square? How do I test if the missiles and the enemies are inside the same square?

Code examples are GREATLY appreicated.

Thanks.

Comment: What does boxSize signify? If it's the size of a "box", then they're not all equal. If it's a positional thing, then you need to be more clear about what it means.

Comment: Great point. Yes, it's the position, I just fixed that.

Comment: So saving coordinates as one value doesn't really work like that. You need at least two coordinate values if you're on a 2D grid

Comment: @JL yeah, that's exactly where I didn't know what to do anymore. What would you recommend I do to achieve what I want to? Pseudocode would be great btw!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're doing with the 2D array or why it contains Integers or why it contains an increasing size in each column, but the general way to do grid-based collision is to have a 2D array of GameObjects. A GameObject in your case could be a Ship, a Missile, or an Enemy.

When one of your GameObjects wants to move, you simply check the 2D array of GameObjects to see what is already in the square you want to move to. If it's empty, you can do the move. If it's not empty, you've got a collision.

Comment: Makes sense. Can you please provide some pseudocode? It would really, really help me out a lot.

Comment: How about you try something out and post a question when you have a specific problem? The pseudocode wouldn't really look much different from my last paragraph though.

Comment: I did exactly what you asked me to. Please check out my new thread http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/69686/grid-based-collision-detection-between-circles?noredirect=1#comment125529_69686